# Lazy Loading images with threshold fails with more than one container (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading, containers, lazy-evaluation, threshold

My site contains three horizontal divs (containers) which all have lazy-loading images within a list view (ul -> li).
They all load completely fine when 'threshold' is set to '0' and all the images load when I scroll to the right.

However, when I set 'threshold' to '500', it is only the first container who lazy loads. The other div containers only start lazy loading until I have scrolled towards the end of the first div-container.

EXAMPLE:
If I try to scroll in the second div-container no images starts to load. The lazy loading only start when the first div-container is scrolled towards its end.

My script:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
  $(function () {
      $("img").lazyload({ container: $(".horizontalBookList1") });
  });
  $(function () {
      $("img").lazyload({ container: $(".horizontalBookList2") });
  });
  $(function () {
      $("img").lazyload({ container: $(".horizontalBookList3") });
  });
  $("img").lazyload({
      effect: "fadeIn"
  });
  $("img").lazyload({
      threshold: 500
  });
  </script>
```

In advance, thank you very much :)

A link to the lazy-load script: http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload

Answer (score 0):

Instead of initialising the plugin five times do it only three times. Once for each container and only for images inside each container. Following should work:

```
$(function() {
    $(".horizontalBookList1 img").lazyload({ 
        container: $(".horizontalBookList1"),
        effect: "fadeIn,"
        threshold: 500
    });
    $(".horizontalBookList2 img").lazyload({ 
        container: $(".horizontalBookList2"),
        effect: "fadeIn,"
        threshold: 500
    });
    $(".horizontalBookList3 img").lazyload({ 
        container: $(".horizontalBookList3"),
        effect: "fadeIn,"
        threshold: 500
    });
};
```